# How can I get all the photos for a specific day when there are no highlights?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I am using Google Photos, and I want to download all the photos taken on a certain day. Normally, I can click the date from the highlights tab, the click All Photos to see all the photos taken on a specific day.

The problem is that sometimes Google decides there were no highlights on a specific day. Without the header to click on, I can't get to a view that shows all the images on a certain day.

The photos are all very similar, so from the 'photo roll' type view it's very hard to determine where the boundary is between one day and the next - I have to open each image in turn to find it.

What can I do? Is there some way of manually selecting highlights to make sure a day shows up in the highlights tab?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved this one as I was typing it. To make a day show up in highlights:

1. Open an image from that day
2. From the 'More' dropdown select 'Highlight'
3. That photo will now show up in Highlights, allowing you to open the day and select all photos.